# Label that wraps around image effect

Tags: html, css

I have a problem that is best illustrated with an image. I have the turquoise block already, but i want this darker area which is inside the red circle. I would prefer an CSS-only solution if this is possible.

[image: This is the effect I want to achieve]

My code so far is this: http://jsfiddle.net/3D2g7/

```
div {
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    background-color: #000;
}

.image-container {
    position: relative;
}

.image-container span {
    position: absolute;
    background-color: #00b9e5;
    padding: 7px 17px;
    top: 7px;
    left: -9px;
    border-top-left-radius: 7px;
    color: #fff;
    text-transform: uppercase;
}
```

Comment: The solution: see below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://jsfiddle.net/HeT72/2/

Use the :after pseudo selector to position the bottom curved border under the span element.

```
div {
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    background-color: #000;
}

.image-container span {
    color: #fff;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    padding: 7px 17px;
    display: inline-block;
    background-color: #00b9e5;
    position: relative;
    left: -7px;
    border-top-left-radius: 7px;
}
.image-container span:after {
    position: absolute;
    left:0;
    z-index:-1;
    background-color: #095F72;
    padding: 7px 17px;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 7px;
    display: block;
    content:'';
  }
```